# Pipe withing conditional interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following interpolation:

```
<div>
    {{ cond1 || cond2 || cond3}}
</div>
```

How can I implement a custom pipe like so:

```
<div>
    {{ cond1 || cond2 || cond3 | customPipe }}
</div>
```

I have tried using brackets to encapsulate the results, and the entire IF statement, so far no luck.

Comment: Add complete code with condition

Comment: You should wrap `cond1 || cond2 || cond3` in braces. Can you please provide a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it with `()`

```
{{cond1 ? (result | customPipe ) : 'something'}}
```

Comment: The funny part is, I tried this beforehand and it did not work, strange. Thanks!